# How to initialize semaphore.h?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, multiprocessing

I have a question. I'am trying to use the semaphore in the kernel module and want to intialize the number of the available buffersize, and the full, and empty variable in the semaphore.

Although I know how to implement it in the userspace by using the code below, I'am having trouble of implementing the same thing in the kernel module.

Is there a different approach when implementing the full and empty in semaphore in kernel module?

Comment: Yes, semantic of `struct semaphore` in the kernel is similar to one for POSIX semaphores. And you have found proper kernel functions analogues. Just use them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your advice. Is it possible to use two seperate semaphores for empty and full?   Currently, I am using it as ex) down(&empty) up(&full) for consumer and producer threads.  if I use two different semapthors for I get stuck when I try to kill all the threads. I think I'am using the semaphors for the kernel the wrong way.

Comment: `I think I'am using the semaphors for the kernel the wrong way.` - Without viewing the code it is difficult to say anything about correctness.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to check to example code? I have added at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Function `down()` performs **uninterruptible** wait. That is why you cannot stop the threads at this point.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Wow! Does this mean I have to use down_interruptable()?

Comment: I am unsure, but `down_interruptible` is unlikely help with kernel threads: `kthread_stop()` awakes waiting threads, but it **sets** some **bit** instead of *emitting a signal*. Without viewing a signal, `_interruptable()` functions do not return but repeat waiting. One possible approach is to **add fake element** into the buffer before `kthread_stop()` call. This will terminate `down(&full)` call, so you may process fake element manually.

Comment: Note, that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. We expect **precise problem** to be completely described **in the question post**. *Answers* refers only to that problem, and *comments* are volatile. Even if related, *different questions* should be asked in *different question posts*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. `<semaphore.h>` is a userspace API (POSIX semaphores), and is not available within the kernel.

There are a number of similar locking APIs within the kernel -- most notably, [`struct semaphore`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/semaphore.h), but also be aware of [`rwlock`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/rwlock.h) as well as alternatives to locking like RCU.

Comment: Yes, I am planning to use struct semaphore. So what I was asking was how to implement the empty and full of semaphore in the kernel space using the struct semaphore.